# Get CGridView to return selected values

Tags: php, sql, yii, cgridview

I would like to return selected values to the CGridView (similar to IN query) using the search function that is generated by Yii.To elaborate further let me use the example below:

Here I return values of the based on the value '34455' (fk_recordid)

```
public function search()
{
    $fk_recordid = '34455'; 
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
    $criteria->compare('fk_recordid',$fk_recordid,true);
    $criteria->compare('babypid',$this->babypid);
    $criteria->compare('babysbn',$this->babysbn);   

    return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

How would I change this code to widen the fk_recordid criteria i.e return records based on several values such as '34455','47859','78956' .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [compare()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail) like you have:

```
$fk_recordid = '34455';
$criteria->compare('fk_recordid',$fk_recordid,true);
```

You could use [addInCondition()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail) like so:

```
$myRecordIds = array('34455','47859','78956');
$criteria->addInCondition('fk_recordid',$myRecordIds);
```

I don't know how you are passing in all of these record ids from the CGridView to the search() function, but once you have them addInCondition() will work. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That has ended my weekend well